# Will Windows 10 ship with Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10-preview, microsoft-edge

The web seems to be full of conflicting messages.

"The existing version of Internet Explorer will ship in Windows 10 alongside Microsoft’s new Spartan browser, the company revealed Thursday." - pcworld, jan 23, 2015 http://www.pcworld.com/article/2874512/spartan-and-ie11-to-coexist-in-windows-10.html

This article from apr 3, 2015 says the same: http://windowsitpro.com/windows-10/internet-explorer-second-class-citizen-windows-10

I can't find sources to the contrary now, but I recall reading a number of sources as recent as Mar 2015 saying that only "some" Windows 10 for "enterprise" will ship with IE.

Confused!

Comment: I feel bad for the author, the format of his question could have used some work, but the question has an answer.  While I might be the first to admit that I am fast on the trigger finger at times, seems, I wasn't fast enough to defend this question

Comment: @Ramhound: It can always be reopened. I'm reluctant to vote to do so right away though till the OP links to these 'sources' he's talking about that make that claim. As it stands now the question is based on hearsay. Perhaps you can edit to improve so it's in a state fit for reopening?

Comment: @Таня: Please edit your question to link to these numerous sources you mention so that this question can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 11 will remain unchanged, which is included on non-mobile versions of Windows 10, to provided the required legacy support in an Enterprise environment.  Devices that run non-mobile versions of Windows 10 will have both Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge on them.

It should be noted that the linked [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/01/22/project-spartan-and-the-windows-10-january-preview-build.aspx) in the author's question describes Microsoft's original plan for Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11.  I am pointing to the Microsoft blog on purpose since thats what the base information in the linked article is from.

The current plan is described in following article [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/24/updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop.aspx) with the following image.  This is an adaption of another answer I made, which answers this answer, removed any content that didn't apply to this question.

[image]

> Project Spartan was built for the next generation of the Web, taking
>   the unique opportunity provided by Windows 10 to build a browser with
>   a modern architecture and service model for Windows as a Service. This
>   clean separation of legacy and new will enable us to deliver on that
>   promise. Our testing with Project Spartan has shown that it is on
>   track to be highly compatible with the modern Web, which means the
>   legacy engine isn’t needed for compatibility.
>
> For Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10 to be an effective solution for
>   legacy scenarios and enterprise customers, it needs to behave
>   consistently with Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1.
>   Hosting our new engine in Internet Explorer 11 has compatibility
>   implications that impact this promise and would have made the browser
>   behave differently on Windows 10.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/24/updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop.aspx)